# Laravel eloquent, how to order custom sortby

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code that works fine:

```
$products = Product::like($search)->whereIn('id', $request->input('product_ids'))->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get(array('products.*'))->sortBy(function($product) use ($sort_order) {
    $number = (isset($sort_order[$product->id])) ? $sort_order[$product->id] : 0;
    return $number;
});
```

This returns the items in ascending order, how do I specify whether I want sortby to return the products in ascending or descending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//$order contains either 'asc' or 'desc'
$products = Product::like($search)->whereIn('id', $request->input('product_ids'))->skip($offset)->take($limit)->get(array('products.*'))->sortBy(function($product) use ($sort_order, $direction) {
    $number = (isset($sort_order[$product->id])) ? $sort_order[$product->id] : 0;
    return ($direction == 'asc') ? $number : -$number;
});
```

Comment: It says the first parameter to orderby is the column that you want to sort by so what would that be in this scenario where I'm not actually sorting on a column as such?

Answer (score 0):

I really don’t understand the query. There’s a lot going on there that really shouldn’t be. For example:

- You’re not selecting data from any other table, so why are you specifying all rows from the `products` table in the `get()` method (`->get(array('products.*'))`)?
- Why are you applying the ordering function to the returned collection instead of just applying the order clause to the query?

With the above, you query could be simplified to something like:

```
$productIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];

$direction = 'asc'; // or desc

$products = Product::like($search)
                   ->whereIn('id', $productIds)
                   ->skip($offset)
                   ->take($limit)
                   ->orderBy('id', $direction)
                   ->get();
```

Also, you don’t need to manually specify the offset and limit if you use the `paginate()` helper method.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sortBy` for ASC (how you used it now) and `sortByDesc` for DESC.